# Check database if username exist in c# textbox

Tags: c#, button

I am planning to check the username based on user input from the text box and I am planning to have the error message immediately after putting the existing username. for now i have this code. I am not experiencing errors but its not working. what am i missing here?

```
protected void btn_Registration_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            string insertQuery = "insert into UserData(Username,Firstname,Lastname,Email,Password,CustomerType,DeliveryAddress,Zip,ContactNumber)values(@Username,@Firstname,@Lastname,@Email,@Password,@CustomerType,@DeliveryAddress,@Zip,@ContactNumber)";
            SqlCommand scm = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUser.Text);
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Firstname", txtFN.Text);
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lastname", txtLN.Text);
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", BusinessLayer.ShoppingCart.CreateSHAHash(txtPW.Text));
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerType", RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.ToString());
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeliveryAddress", txtAddress.Text);
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Zip", txtZip.Text);
            scm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactNumber", txtContact.Text);

            scm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Session["Contact"] = txtContact.Text;
            Session["Email"] = txtEmail.Text;
            Session["DeliveryAddress"] = txtAddress.Text;
            label_register_success.Text = ("Registration Successful!");
            //Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error:" + ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    protected void txtUser_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack == true)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from UserDAta where Username='" + txtUser.Text + "'", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Imagemessage.Visible = true;
            lblusercheck.Visible = true;
            Imagemessage.ImageUrl = "NotAvailable.jpg";
            lblusercheck.Text = "Username already exists.";
        }
        else
        {
            Imagemessage.Visible = true;
            lblusercheck.Visible = true;
            Imagemessage.ImageUrl = "Available.gif";
            lblusercheck.Text = "You can choose this username.";
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

TextChange Event would not be called upon any single key press. What you should do is to use javascript to create a postback to the server (for example using __doPostBack) in the client side function **keyup**

Also, this would be a postback and you should not check for !isPostBack in the Handler.

Update:

```
Markup:
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt" onkeyup="check(this);" />


Javascript
function check(txt) {

    __doPostBack('Control to Update', 'Filter--'+txt.value);
}

codebehind:
form_load:
parameter = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
if (parameter != null && parameter.startsWith("Filter--"))
{
    //Do your check here.
}
```

I don't like this kind of coding as it is messy.

Comment: can you give me a sample?

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/20abe2/how-to-check-user-name-or-email-availability-using-Asp-Net/